# Why is my Bootstrap Toggle Navbar disappearing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So the "hamburger" toggle navbar icon seems to be invisible after I collapse the page to the point that it's supposed to appear.  Both the 3 icon bars and the actual button are invisible.  However, it still seems to work in that it drops down when clicked on.  I have gone through the styles effecting it using the 'Inspect Element' function in Google Chrome, toggling and changing numerous styles to no avail.

Can anyone help me understand why it's doing this?

[image]

Here's a picture illustrating the problem, and my code:

```
<style>

    /*body {
      background-color: #c0c0c0;
    }*/

    @media (max-width: 767px) {

    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      /*.navbar-nav {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        float:none;
      }*/

      body {

      }

      .navbar-nav > li {
        border-left: 1px solid;
      }

      .navbar {
        border-radius-bottom-left: 5px;
        border-radius-bottom-right: 5px;
       /* background-color: #99ccff;*/
        width: 100%;
      }

      .nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus {
        /*background-color: #eee !important;*/
      }
    }
    .navbar {
     /* background-color: #99ccff; */
      border: 1px solid; 
    }


    </style>

    <title> Bootstrap Testing </title>
  </head>
  <body role = "document">

  <div class = "row-fluid">
    <div class = "col-lg-9">
      <img src = "pics/edviewrateBanner.png">
    </div>

    <div class = "col-lg-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary visible-lg">Sign In</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class = "row-fluid">
     <div class = "col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-9 hidden-xs">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" style = "visibility: hidden;">ButtonToTakeUpSpace</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class = "row-fluid">
    <div class = "col-lg-12">
      <nav class = "navbar" role =  "navigation">
         <div class = "container-fluid">

          <div class = "navbar-header">
            <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#mainNavbarInfo">
              <span class = "sr-only"> Toggle navigation </span>
              <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
              <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
              <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class = "navbar-brand visible-xs visible-sm" href = "#"> EdViewRate</a>
          </div>

          <!-- Begin Navbar items -->
          <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "mainNavbarInfo">
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class = "active"><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home </a> </li>
              <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> SLO Generator </a> </li>
              <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> SLO Tutorial </a> </li>
              <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Sign up  </a></li>

            <li class = "dropdown visible-xs visible-sm visible-md">
              <a class = "dropdown-toggle" href = "#" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Sign In <strong class = "caret"></strong></a>
              <div class = "dropdown-menu" style = "padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                  <form action="[YOUR ACTION]" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                    <input id="user_username" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="user[username]" size="30" />
                    <input id="user_password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="user[password]" size="30" />
                    <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" />
                    <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>

                    <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In" />
                  </form>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>

          </div>

        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you set this up as a jsFiddle?

Comment: Yes, I'll do that from now on.  Thanks Juhana for the edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't specified the "theme" to use for the navbar. You must a class of `navbar-default` or `navbar-inverse` along with the `navbar` class on your `nav` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/65KdX/1/

In doing this, all the Bootstrap CSS appears to do to the `navbar-toggle` is apply a `border-color` of `#ddd` to it. You could probably omit the `navbar-default` class, but there's no telling what other styling problems with the `navbar` you're likely to run into. Better to apply that class and then override the specific things you don't want/need.

Comment: It also adds `background-color: #888;` to `.icon-bar`